# Format cell text color

Tags: javascript, tabulator

This column formatter sets background color fine, but then I cannot see the text at all.

```js
function truthFormatter(cell, formatterParams, onRendered) {
    var cellValue = cell.getValue();
    var cellElement = cell.getElement();
    if (cellValue == "T") {
    cellElement.style.backgroundColor = "#0000B3";
    cellElement.style.color = "#FFFFFF";
    }
    else if (cellValue == "F") {
    cellElement.style.backgroundColor = "#B30000";
    cellElement.style.color = "#FFFFFF";
    }
}
```

Chrome's style inspector on one of these cells suggests everything should be fine:

```
element.style {
    width: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 179);
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    height: 25px;
}
```

I get the same behavior in a stand-alone, test configuration---no other CSS applied.

Also, text in cells where the formatter should not apply is not visible---even though style inspection here also seems to be fine:

```
element.style {
    width: 151px;
    text-align: right;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    height: 32px;
}
```

[Link to screenshot of table as rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hH4Y3.png)

[Link to rendering without the formatter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awfsa.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your line of :

```
cellElement.style.color = "#FFFFFF";
```

Should work just fine, i have run some tests and it works this end.

I would suggest using your browser inspector to see what CSS is overriding it.

You are also not returning the value of the cell in the formatter, so nothing will will be displayed inside the cell.

you need to add this line to the bottom of your formatter function

```
return cell.getValue();
```

Comment: It does not seem like that is the issue.  Please see my refined question.

Comment: could you post a screenshot of your table

Comment: Link to screenshot added.

Comment: the issue wasn't that your text was the wrong color, it is that it wasn't there at all, you weren't returning the cell value from the formatter. I have updated my answer to explain how to do this